# Vscode python debug works uncorrectedly in Windows + shell terminal environment

Tags: python, shell, cmd, vscode-debugger

## Vscode Python debug problem

My environment

```
Windows 11
VScode 1.81.1
MingW64 Bash (as VScode integrated terminal)
```

When pressing `F5` for debugging python file, terminal shows:

```
#  cmd /C "D:\Sci\Anaconda\envs\torch\python.exe c:\Users\shuch\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 60484 -- D:\Date\LTS_23-6-20_ML\2_BasicML\inference_cnn.py "
Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22621.2134]
(c) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。

D:\Date\LTS_23-6-20_ML>
```

It entered into interactive mode of CMD waiting for commands

## Performance of different terminals

I tried to test in terminal:

MingW64 Bash

```
# cmd /c echo "test"
Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22621.2134]
(c) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。

C:\Users\shuch>
```

```
# cmd //c echo "test"
test
```

Powershell

```
PS C:\Users\shuch> cmd /c echo "test"
test
```

```
PS C:\Users\shuch> cmd //c echo "test"
Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22621.2134]
(c) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。

C:\Users\shuch>
```

So my questions are:

- Why `cmd /c` works differently in shell and powershell?
- How to fix vscode debug problem without changing integrated terminal?

Comment: I have not installed *VSCode*, but the `cmd` command line is definitely incorrect according to help output by `cmd` on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`. The command line should be either `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /S /C "D:\Sci\Anaconda\envs\torch\python.exe c:\Users\shuch\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter\..\..\debugpy\launcher 60484 -- D:\Date\LTS_23-6-20_ML\2_BasicML\inference_cnn.py"` with just ``\`` in paths and with option `/S` as the entire command line is enclosed in `"` or ...

Comment: `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C "D:\Sci\Anaconda\envs\torch\python.exe" "C:\Users\shuch\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter\..\..\debugpy\launcher 60484" -- "D:\Date\LTS_23-6-20_ML\2_BasicML\inference_cnn.py"`. It is not clear for me if the argument for `python.exe` is `"C:\Users\shuch\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter\..\..\debugpy\launcher"` or `"C:\Users\shuch\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter\..\..\debugpy\launcher 60484"`.

Comment: I suppose that `--` and `D:\Date\LTS_23-6-20_ML\2_BasicML\inference_cnn.py` are arguments for the *Python* script `launcher` or `launcher 60484`. The help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window not only explains how the argument(s) after option `/C` or option `/K` are interpreted depending on various criteria, but also that file name (or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` (or literally to interpret `<>|`) must be enclosed in `"`. The command line posted in question might miss the necessary `"` around the arguments.

Comment: I found an issue about [MinGW64 execute cmd with shell](https://superuser.com/questions/1413103/execute-cmd-command-with-shell). But I still have no idea to fix VSCode python debugger.

Comment: @Mofi I suppose that the key is MinGW64 Shell think `/C` is a  path not a argument according to  "Performance of different terminals" I posed above and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1413103/execute-cmd-command-with-shell) . Well what you mentioned above, how terminal deals with `"` is also interesting

Answer (score 0):

MSYS employs a method for handling the conversion of Windows to Unix paths.

All we need to do is set `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL` to `*`.

https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/#automatic-unix-windows-path-conversion.